# Symfony entity validation verify foreign key exists

Tags: symfony, validation, docker, entity

I would like to be able to use entity validator constraints to verify if the foreign key book_id is valid, please see below:

Book.php

```
/**
 * Book
 *
 * @ORM\Table("book")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BookRepository")
 */
class Book
{
     /**
      * @var integer
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     max = 250,
     *     maxMessage = "Name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     *     groups={"create","update"}
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Loan", mappedBy="book", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    protected $loan;
}
```

Loan.php

```
/**
 * Loan
 *
 * @ORM\Table("loan")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LoanRepository")
 */
class Loan
{
     /**
      * @var integer
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="book_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $book_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     max = 500,
     *     maxMessage = "Person cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters",
     *     groups={"create","update"}
     * )
     */
    private $person;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="loan")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    protected $book;
}
```

Here is how I am currently validating the loan entity

```
    $loan = new Loan();
    $loan->setPerson($person);
    $loan->setBookId($id);

    /** @var ConstraintViolation $error */
    foreach ($this->get('validator')->validate($loan,null,['create'])->getIterator() as $index => $error) {
        $errorMessages[] = $error->getMessage();
    }
```

I figured maybe I can add a custom validator like this to the loan entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message = "The book does not exist")
 * @return bool
 */
public function isBookLegal(BookRepository $bookRepository)
{
    return !$bookRepository->fetchById($this->book_id);
}
```

But I end up with the follow exception:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function 
AppBundle\Entity\Loan::isBookLegal(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

Comment: first of all assign the 1st paramater from the foreach to a variable and then use it in foreach, that's just nasty. Second, when you call your `isBookLegal` you call it without parameter - that's why you get this message.

Comment: But how can I call isBookLegal when it is triggered via validate? In other words how can I get validate to pass the parameter into this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should not have both `$book_id` and `$book` in your `Loan` entity.  You should remove `$book_id`, which is enough for your entity relationship.

Then, all you need to do is add an `@Assert\NotBlank()` on `$book`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

...

 /**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="loan")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  */
protected $book;
```

I'm not sure what code you are using to get all of your loans, but as Edwin states that's not really good form.  You want want something more like:

```
foreach ($loans as $loan) {
    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($loan);
    // do something here if there is an error
}
```

The assertion function you wrote isn't going to work because you can't pass in a value to your `isBookLegal()` function there, nor can you ever use the database connection/repository from within your Entity class.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish without greater context here.  Doctrine is already going to validate your `$book` member because of your `@ORM\OneToOne` annotation in the first place.  You don't have to perform any additional validation.  I'm guessing you are trying to pass in a value directly to `$book_id`, which is incorrect.  You should only be passing already-valid `$book` entities to your `Loan` class, via `$loan->setBook(Book $book);`

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer, I think i'm miss understanding how doctrine entity relationships work. If I remove book_id what should I set as name in this: @ORM\JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="id")

Comment: Oh I think I see now. So I don't need to implicitly set book_id as a class property because doctrine will work out that it needs to add that column as specified by name.

Comment: That is correct. Also check this out here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html You can have Doctrine auto-generate all of your entities for you if your database is already created.

Comment: All this is going to do is check that the book field is not null https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html, what the OP wants is to check that the book ID exists in his database